# Bold text in react component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I can't understand how to make bold text 'first' here?

```
React.createElement('li', null, `first: port`),
```

Comment: `<b>first: </b> port`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `JSX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
React.createElement(
  "li",
  null,
  React.createElement("b", null, "first:"),
  " port", 
);
```